# from WordPress .htaccess wanted to call out the code igniter project

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have added these rule:

```
RewriteRule    "^redemptionUAT/(.*)$"  "http://30.178.255.56/$1"  [P]
```

in the WordPress .htaccess file(Please download the file from here [.htaccess](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rhw54p9RnPypS3nHUm3DGjOy5c-Fcx3d/view?usp=sharing) ) and wanted to access the Codeigniter project which is deployed on this server:- 30.178.255.56.
So whenever I try to access the CI project like these https://Doamin.com/redemptionUAT/admin it's not getting loaded.
it is having the apache2 and  the module installed are (a2enmod rewrite proxy proxy_http proxy_fcgi)

So need help to write a valid rewrite rule for these.

note :- I have mentioned the dummy domain and IP , I don't want to disclose it.

Comment: Where in the WordPress `.htaccess` file have you placed this directive? Please include your complete `.htaccess` file. Have you confirmed that mod_proxy (and associated modules) are installed on your server? Whilst it's recommended to exemplify domain names and IP addresses, you should still ensure the resulting code is valid. The "IP address" you've used is obviously not valid. [RFC5737](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5737) identifies reserved IP addresses that are safe to use in documentation/examples.

Comment: @MrWhite Please download the file from here .htaccess (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rhw54p9RnPypS3nHUm3DGjOy5c-Fcx3d/view?usp=sharing) and also regarding the IP i have created the dummy IP , i don't to disclose the domain name and IP, also regarding the module (a2enmod rewrite proxy proxy_http  proxy_fcgi)

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: You should not link to external resources. Edit your question to include the actual `htaccess` file.